# What is happens before relations in Synchronization? What is premature object leak?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading [SynchronizedMethodsOracleDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) and I am unable to understand this concept.
It says that.

> Warning: When constructing an object that will be shared between
>   threads, be very careful that a reference to the object does not
>   "leak" prematurely. For example, suppose you want to maintain a List
>   called instances containing every instance of class. You might be
>   tempted to add the following line to your constructor:
>   instances.add(this); But then other threads can use instances to
>   access the object before construction of the object is complete.

What does this mean?

It also states that :-

> Second, when a synchronized method exits,It automatically establishes
>   a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a
>   synchronized method for the same object.

What is the meaning of happens before relationship?

Can someone elaborate on these two points? Thanks.

Comment: happens-before emphasizes on serialization of transactions

Comment: 1. Don't get yourself in a situation where the instance (referred to by `this`) is shared before constructor is finished initializing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Premature Leak

Leaking the reference to an object that is not yet completely created.

Example:

```
class Someclass{

   public SomeClass(List list){
        list.add(this); //this is leaked outside before complete creation, constructor is still not complete

        //do some other chores to create this object
   }
}
```

Some Thread 2:

```
listPassedToSomeclass //Thread is using this list and working on something
```

Now on calling add on the list from constructor you published the `this` reference in the list which is shared by other thread, and now it can see the this reference added in the list before even the constructor has ended (Which means that the object is not in stable state and not properly created).

There is a possibility that the Thread 2 will get all sorts of weird behavior on using your object as the state will be unstable. So avoid leaking references.

### Happens Before

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First question:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example implements Runnable {

    private static LinkedList<ListEntry> objList;

    public static class ListEntry {
        public int var = -1;
        public ListEntry(List<ListEntry> objList, int var) {
            synchronized (objList) {
                objList.add(this);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            this.var = var;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        objList = new LinkedList<>();
        new ListEntry(objList, 1);
        for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
            new Thread(new Example()).start();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
            ListEntry lastEntry;
            synchronized (objList) {
                lastEntry = objList.getLast();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            int lastVar = lastEntry.var;
            new ListEntry(objList, lastVar + 1);
            System.out.println(lastVar);
            if (lastVar < 0)
                throw new RuntimeException("lastVar = " + lastVar);
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this code the RuntimeException will be thrown from time to time because the last object added to the list has not finished construction yet, so it's var instance will have the initial -1 value. This can happen because you "leaked" the object reference (this) in the constructor. Couldn't come up with a better example.

Second question:
A synchronized method guarantees that it is finished (has happened) before any subsequent invocation of that method takes place. Don't know how to describe it better.

Comment: do you mean to say different threads are creating ListEntryObjects but they all are using same List instance?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the instances list. In your Object's constructor, you add `this` to that list.

The article is saying that instances is shared amongst multiple threads. So at the point that you add `this`, the other threads are able to access it. However, since you are adding it in your object's constructor, the object isn't fully instantiated yet (until it returns from the constructor).

So basically you'd be sharing a reference to an object that isn't fully instantiated.

For the second point, a happens before relationship means that the synchronized object block is guaranteed to be visible to other threads accessing that data since it will always execute when the synchonized object can be acquired. Not sure if I explained that properly.

Check out this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html