# Calling overridden child methods in a parent constructor, is there a practical solution to my problem?

Tags: java, constructor, overriding

The code below demonstrates why you should never call an overridden method in a constructor.

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public Parent() {
        print();
    }
    public abstract void print();
}
public class Child extends Parent {
    private int i;
    public Child(int i) {
        super();
        this.i = i;
    }
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("This code doesn't work, i = " + i); // i is not initalized
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a clean solution that will allow the overridden method to run after the child class is initialized, but without having to physically call that method in the child's own constructor. In essence, I want my abstract parent class not only to define an abstract method that the child must have, but also define that it needs to be ran during initialization. Any ideas?

Comment: No, there is no solution. There is only a rule: do not leak premature objects. A consequence of this rule is that we should only call private or final methods from a constructor. Also, notice that the explicit call to `super()` is superfluous and inserted implicitly if we do not add it explicitly. Furthermore we can even "break" the code on a more fundamental level by declaring `private int i` as `final`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my real code I have an abstract class that many classes extend from. I really hate the idea that in every child class I need to invoke the same overridden methods in the child's constructor. I was hoping for possible different approach but that achieves the same goal.

Answer (score 1):

#### Prelude

Before we begin the discussion, I would like to point out that the explicit call to `super()` in `Child`'s constructor is superfluous and added implicitly if we remove it (see [JLS, §8.8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7)). So we can simplify `Child` to:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    private int i;

    public Child(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("This code doesn't work, i = " + i); // i is not initalized
    }
}
```

This is to show that this problem may even hit programmers who do not know of the implicit `super()` call and/or do not use `super()`.

---

#### The actual question

We cannot prevent such behaviour. There is only a rule we can follow: [Do not leak premature objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107128/what-is-happens-before-relations-in-synchronization-what-is-premature-object-le). A consequence of this rule is that we should only call private or final methods from constructors. In the code presented, we violate this rule. This allows us to "break" the code even more by declaring field `private int i` in class `Child` as `final`:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  private final int i;

  public Child(int i) {
    this.i = i;
  }

  @Override
  public void print() {
    System.out.println("This code doesn't work, i = " + i); // i is not initalized
  }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/XFwjnO)

We would expect that `i` has one and only one value, but we clearly see that `i` changes its value.

---

#### Remark

In the original code, the field `i` is (always) initialized. This stems from the fact that non-final fields, other than local variables, are always initialized with a default value (primitives with `0` or `false`, reference types with `null`).